# Can anyone help. I want to make a div which expands its width continuously till it reaches a certain width

Tags: javascript, html, css

Can anyone help. I want to make a div which expands its width continuously till it reaches a certain width.
The max width it can reach is 540px. And it should start at 75px. I have tried making it, but I can't here's html and css.

```css
.Loading-Screen {
  background-color: black;
  color: aliceblue;
  height: 400px;
  width: 600px;
  border-radius: 45px 45px 45px 45px;
  font-size: large;
  font-family: monospace;
  margin: auto;
}

.Loading-Box {
  background-color: gray;
  color: aliceblue;
  height: 75px;
  width: 550px;
  border-radius: 25px 25px 45px 45px;
  font-size: large;
  font-family: monospace;
  margin: auto;
}

.Loading-Line {
  background-color: #1a1a1a;
  color: aliceblue;
  height: 65px;
  width: 75px;
  max-width: 540px;
  border-radius: 25px 25px 45px 45px;
  font-size: large;
  font-family: monospace;
  margin-top: -2.5%;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 1%;
}

.Loading-Screen a {
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.LoadOK {
  height: 50px;
  width: 135px;
  color: tomato;
  background-color: #1a1a1a;
  border: 0;
  border-radius: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.LoadOK:hover {
  height: 70px;
  width: 175px;
  margin-top: -2.5%;
}

.Loading-Screen a:hover {
  font-size: 40px;
}
```

```html
<body bgcolor="#1a1a1a">
  <center>
    <div class="Loading-Screen"><br><br><br><br>
      <h1><a>Web OS</a></h1>
      <br><br>
      <button class="LoadOK" onclick="">Load...</button><br><br><br><br><br>
      <div class="Loading-Box"><br>
        <div class="Loading-Line" id="Load"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </center>
</body>
```

When loadOK is clicked, loading-line should expand till 540px. Hopefully you understand my query. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

By 'expanding its width' are you talking about when the size of the browser is changed? If so, then you will want to adjust your css so that it is responsive (the content will adjust based on the size of the browser/device).

For example:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 900px){
  and everything put within here will respond to the browser/device changes
}
```

Take a look at this for further clarification:

https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp

Answer (score 0):

Try this, Hope you need this.

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style> 
div {
  width: 75px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
  transition: width 2s;
}

</style>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#button").click(function(){
    $('#expand').css({
      'width':'540px',
    })
  });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="expand"></div>

<button id="button">Expand</button>

</body>
</html>
```

you can check the codepen here https://codepen.io/asad7880/pen/JjKpBdN

Answer (score 0):

HTML

```html
<button class="LoadOK" onclick="loading()">Load...</button>
```

CSS:

```css
.Loading-Line {
 ....
  transition: 1s width;
}
.Loading-Line.active {
  width: 540px;
}
```

JS

```js
function loading() {
  const load = document.getElementById('Load');
  load.classList.add('active');
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ttquang1063750/6vygkxha/4/

Answer (score 0):

**width**: will set element width to the given value.

**min-width**: will make sure your width doesn't go below some values.

First set min-width to 75px instaed of only width. Add `transition: width 2s ease-in-out; max-width: 540px;` to the element and you can manipulate it's width by javascript function;

```js
function load(){
 document.getElementById('Load').style.width = '100%'
}

load();
```

```css
.Loading-Line{
  max-width: 540px;
  min-width: 75px;
  background-color: #1a1a1a;
  color: aliceblue; 
  height: 65px;
  border-radius: 25px 25px 45px 45px;
  font-size: large;
  font-family: monospace;
  margin-top: -2.5%;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 1%;
  transition: width 2s ease-in-out;
}
```